# Passing props not working Material UI react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I was trying to pass a prop to modify the button style. In this case, I'd like the button to be "blue" and backgroundColor "orange".

I passed a cool="true" in when calling Button, but the button is still "red" in "yellow", as if the cool state is false..

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

/* This is an example of passing props */
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  buttonStyle: (props) => {
    return {
      color: props.cool ? "blue" : "red",
      backgroundColor: props.cool ? "orange" : "yellow",
    };
  },
});

function App(props) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  console.log(classes);
  return (
    <>
      <Button cool="true" className={classes.buttonStyle}>
        Click me!
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

thanks for the answers. Below fixes the problem. I was wondering if it is possible to include the "cool" modifier in the <Button ..> so that it is easier to read, since return () has many parts besides button.

```
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles({ cool: true });
  console.log(classes);
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className={classes.textStyle}>Let's roll this app out.</h1>
      <Button className={classes.buttonStyle}>Click me!</Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For passing props to your styles you should pass props directly to useStyles method:

```js
const classes = useStyles(props);
```

or

```js
const classes = useStyles({ someSpecificProp });
```

Comment: hmm i added `const classes = useStyles(props)` and it doesn't fix the problem?

Comment: check this example - https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: const classes = useStyles({ cool: true })

Comment: Yes! this indeed fix the problem. Is there a way to write it in the <Button ...>? This way it is easier to know "cool" modifies the Button. Because there are many other things in the return ()

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure about your case, but you can create your own Button component and add this logic there.

Comment: You can't directly pass the cool prop to the material-ui-button because it doesn't accept it . What you need here is a wrapper on top of the material-ui-button .

Comment: const Button = ({ cool, ...props }) => {
    const classes = useStyles({ cool })
    return <MaterialButton {...props} />
}

Comment: @Shyam ok maybe that's why. In styled components i was able to add "cool" direct in <button cool="true"...>. I thought MUI would be the same..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the styles of the button using component props, then create a separate component that changes the button styles according to the props.

**CoolButton.jsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

/* This is an example of passing props */
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  buttonStyle: (props) => {
    return {
      color: props.cool ? "blue" : "red",
      backgroundColor: props.cool ? "orange" : "yellow"
    };
  }
});

function CoolButton({ cool }) {
  const classes = useStyles({ cool });
  return (
    <>
      <Button className={classes.buttonStyle}>Click me!</Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default CoolButton;
```

**App.js**

```js
import CoolButton from "./CoolButton";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <CoolButton cool="true">Click me!</CoolButton>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-button-8its7

Let me know if you need further support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const useStyles = props => makeStyles({
  buttonStyle: {
      color: props.cool ? "blue" : "red",
      backgroundColor: props.cool ? "orange" : "yellow",
  },
});
```

And call it:

```
const classes = useStyles(props)();
```